# Why are you telling me to undo my vote when my vote is locked in?

Tags: support, voting, tooltips

When I hover over the upvote or downvote arrows on a post where I have voted, I see the following tooltip "this answer is useful (click again to undo)".

[image: highlighted vote up tooltip]

I never really noticed the phrase "click again to undo" as I always knew that I could do that. I also knew about vote locking after, I think, 15 minutes.

So, I thought that this message meant that my vote could be changed because of an edit. However, there had not been any edits on that post, so I clicked the vote button to check the message and saw: "You last voted on this answer yesterday. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

[image: your vote is locked in message]

So my question is: why am I being told that I can undo my vote and then told, in fact, that I cannot undo my vote?

Shouldn't the phrase "click again to undo" only appear when I can, in fact, undo my vote?

Comment: It's worth noting that whether you can undo your vote or not is calculated on the fly when you attempt to remove your vote.

Comment: It is so irritating to get such misleading guidance; they should have just made some javascript, and it should tell you that your vote is locked in in advance, so you're not bothered to click at all

Answer (score 6):

It is intended to find a way to inform the functionality. Something like this would be much more objective for tooltips:

First click (unvoted) up:

> If you find this question/answer helpful, you can click positive here.

First click (unvoted) down:

> If you find this question/answer not helpful, you can click here.

For voted up:

> You *upvoted* this question. If the vote is not blocked or the post owner edited the content, you can perform a second click to reverse the vote.

For voted down:

> You *downvoted* this question. If the vote is not blocked or the post owner edited the content, you can perform a second click to reverse the vote.

It must be taken into consideration that a label/popup that inform a functionality does not indicate or suggest that it will work... since the operation will depend on other metrics and considerations that the system has.

Well, it is also important that if I could, in the popup/label of the up and down vote arrow, I would add the link to the help page of each site:

> For more information about negative votes visit the help [site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: Or maybe "If your vote is not locked in then click again to undo your vote". I think reversing your vote would imply changing from an upvote to a downvote, for example.

Comment: of course i have update mi answer...

Comment: "If the vote is not blocked" This seems to explain the feature with itself. Perhaps it would be better to describe the actual mechanism? "For a short while after voting as well as after the post owner edited the content, clicking this button reverses the vote."

Comment: @MisterMiyagi creo que tienes razón.